# Allow some sub-directories of directiories that have restricted access by .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

with .htaccess i created auth limitation on some directories, and i want to allow access to only one of their subdirectory. can you help me how to achieve that?

tnx in adv!

**UPDATED:** my current .htaccess contains next:

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/mysite/httpdocs/passwds/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "In development..."
AuthType Basic
<Limit GET POST>
require valid-user
</Limit>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put .htaccess in one directory, that specific directory and all its children, receive same policy. That means, if you put in any children directory another .htaccess file, it can modify any previously defined policy, same as its parent .htaccess.

Add "Satisfy Any" to the child .htaccess

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Satisfy any
```

See [apache "Satisfy" docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#satisfy), it SHOULD work, as this is only solution.

Comment: i know that, but which policy to add? "allow from all" gives me an error

Comment: Depends on what you have already set. Add your current .htaccess file contents, as an example.

Comment: only that? i'm getting "Forbidden" message. also tried to add "allow from all", and geting same result. just to add that directory have 755 permission.

Comment: Check docs about satisfy, see if your main htaccess is correct.

Comment: yes, you are right, problem was that directory browse is disabled. when i use link directly to file, it works nice. thank you!